# Can Guice be configured to hide the class path in stack traces?

Tags: debugging, guice, stack-trace, readability

Guice's stack traces can get so verbose that they are very painful to read.  Here's an example:

```
1) No implementation for java.util.Set<com.mydomain.myapp.android.activities.catbrowser.generalizedbrowser.listview.helpers.databaseitem.itemmanipulators.ItemManipulator<com.mydomain.myapp.flash.Cat>> annotated with @com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted(value=) was bound.
  while locating java.util.Set<com.mydomain.myapp.android.activities.catbrowser.generalizedbrowser.listview.helpers.databaseitem.itemmanipulators.ItemManipulator<com.mydomain.myapp.flash.Cat>> annotated with @com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted(value=)
```

...

If I could hide the classpath, it would look like:

```
1) No implementation for Set<ItemManipulator<Cat>> annotated with @Assisted(value=) was bound.
  while locating Set<ItemManipulator<Cat>> annotated with @Assisted(value=)
```

Is there any way to configure Guice to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the answer is no.

If you take look at [guice source code](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/source/browse/) you will find `com.google.inject.internal.Errors` class that is responsible for building error messages. In this class it is coded that the `Key` is converting the following way:

```
  new Converter<Key>(Key.class) {
    public String toString(Key key) {
      if (key.getAnnotationType() != null) {
        return key.getTypeLiteral() + " annotated with "
            + (key.getAnnotation() != null ? key.getAnnotation() : key.getAnnotationType());
      } else {
        return key.getTypeLiteral().toString();
      }
    }
  }
```

Next step is to take a look at `TypeLiteral#toString` method:

```
  @Override public final String toString() {
    return MoreTypes.typeToString(type);
  }
```

Where `MoreTypes#typeToString` is a static method that cannot be configured

```
  public static String typeToString(Type type) {
    return type instanceof Class ? ((Class) type).getName() : type.toString();
  }
```