# How can I hide long class paths in stack traces to make them readable?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, stack-trace, readability

Often stack traces can get so verbose from long class paths that they are very painful to read.  Here's an example:

```
    1) No implementation for java.util.Set<
com.mydomain.myapp.android.activities.catbrowser.generalizedbrowser.listview.
helpers.databaseitem.itemmanipulators.ItemManipulator<
 com.mydomain.myapp.flash.Cat>> annotated with
 @com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted(value=) was bound.
      while locating
 java.util.Set<
  com.mydomain.myapp.android.activities.catbrowser.generalizedbrowser.listview.
  helpers.databaseitem.itemmanipulators.ItemManipulator<
   com.mydomain.myapp.flash.Cat>> annotated with 
   @com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted(value=)
```

...

If I could trim the class path, only showing class names and methods, it would look like this:

```
1) No implementation for 
   Set<ItemManipulator<Cat>> annotated with @Assisted(value=) was bound.
   while locating Set<ItemManipulator<Cat>> annotated with @Assisted(value=)
```

...

I first asked this as a [Guice-specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8766843/403455), but realized it applies to stack traces in general.  Is there any way to configure Java or Eclipse to do this natively?  If not, is there a plugin or even external tool to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the default `UncaughtExceptionHandler` and modify the stack trace before printing to `System.err`.  You may have to play around with the regex, but this will work:

```
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);
            e.printStackTrace(ps);
            String withoutClasspaths = baos.toString().replaceAll("(\\w+\\.){2,}(\\w*)", "$2");
            System.err.println(withoutClasspaths);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To produce more readable traces, paste the stack trace into Notepad++ and the following regular expression.  The same expression could also be used in a scripting language.

I paste the trace into [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and use the following search and replace settings.

**Search pattern**: `\w[a-z\d_\.]+\.([A-Z][A-Za-z\d_]*)`

**Replace with**: `\1`

**Search Settings**: `match case` enabled, `Regular expression` search mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you use logback, then you can use layout to output logs in any way you like
http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html.

Outputting a class like java.lang.String as j.l.String is quite common in stack traces